# Angular: can we return a string from a service and display it in multiple components?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-services, angular-httpclient

I have a service and a method in it which returns a string, on ngOnInIt() that method gets called, but I'm trying to put that returned value in a variable to display in template.

Tried using observable but didn't help so far

**Service**:

```
FetchUsername() {

this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/fetch_name", {email: 
"sid@Yahoo.com"}).subscribe(
  success => {   

    var success_json = success.json();

    // console.log(success_json.message);

    return success_json.message;

  },
  error => {console.log(error)}
)

}
```

**Component.ts**:

```
username: string; 

ngOnInit() {
    this.username = this.crudService.FetchUsername();
}
```

Can I ?

- call the service once, store the resultant value from HTTP call in a variable in that service;
- from other components, I would no longer need the HTTP call and can just read from that variable instead of having to call the service again and again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're subscribing an storing the result from the api call inside the `success_json` variable in your **service.ts** file; And you're calling your service from the component.ts file and expecting a value to be stored in **this.username**

relevant **service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DemoService {
  urlSO: string = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/8149783?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow'
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  FetchUsername() {
    return this.http.get(this.urlSO);
  }
}
```

relevant **component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DemoService } from './demo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = '';
  username: any;
  constructor(private serv: DemoService) {
    this.serv.FetchUsername().subscribe(
      dataa => { console.log(dataa); this.username = dataa }
      , errr => { console.log("error:", errr); }
    )
  }
}
```

working [stackblitz to showcase this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yhm8ik)

**EDIT** in light of comments below:
Service are used to centralize all outside (DB) communications. If your different components (maybe these different URLs are accessed via routes, maybe these different components are on the same page) need updated data, then they should call the service themselves; if you need a single instance of data from a service, you can fetch once (in a component) and pass around amongst your components;

You want to use a service as a repository of data where it is fetched once (via http) and then accessed through local variable... This will not be possible in my opinion. A service is injected in each component and therefore, there will be separate instances of these services and you wouldn't be able to achieve this.

Comment: this way in each component i have to subscribe and then display value on screen..

Comment: i want to minimize the process of subscribing each time rather subscribe once in service return the username to the component and then just display that username all the time

Comment: What do you mean by subscribing each time?... the constructor is fired once, values will be subscribed once also

Comment: subscribe in different components, if i have 5 components then i have to repeat the code in  relevant component.ts file in all components..

Comment: you can repeat the code... or... if the values you are subscribing to don't change, you can subscribe the values once in the parent component and pass to the childs via @Input

Comment: can i return a string from service and then handle that string to display in component  ? any suggestions please? thanks

Comment: You want to use a service as a repository of data where it is fetched once (via http) and then accessed through local variable... This will not be possible in my opinion. A service is injected in each component and therefore, there will be separate instances of these services and you wouldn't be able to achieve this.

Comment: so i have to rewrite the same code to show username in all components or use input() right?

Comment: if you need it just for showing the username, you can design your application in way that only one components fetches from the service; this one component is present at all times (in the primary component), while the other components shown/changed via routing;

Comment: I'll vote this question up so that more people get to see this and can review our conclusion... can i request that you vote this up also? you can mark it accepted if we get more backing from Angular gurus on stack overflow